# How to do a FQL query with JS SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

This is my code but doesn't work:

```
FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid=100002306311953'
        },
        function(data) {
            alert(data.uid);
        }
);
                });
```

I get "undefined" in the alert.
Why ?

Comment: the response returned is inside an Object, i updated the answer.

Comment: becaues data is not an object by an array of objects. Do this, `alert(data[0].uid);`

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to SO!

You can use the FB.api function by passing the fql.query method and the query,

A simple query that returns the current user, name:

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid = me()'
}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var res = data[0].name;
    alert(res);
    }
);
```

FB Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/